# How to add interesting Stack Overflow tags in favorites

Tags: discussion, tags, user-interface

I don't find favorite tags; I could see only *watched tags* and *ignored tags*. Where can I find favorite tags?

Comment: There are no "favourite" tags. There are only "watched" tags. Which you can watch because they are your favourites, or any other reason. And no way of marking a subset of those watched tags as your favourite tags for watching.

Answer (score 2):

Favortie tags were changed into watched tags and ignored tags. You can check this post:

['Favorite Tags' is now 'Tag Watching'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312180/favorite-tags-is-now-tag-watching)

---

You can go to the tag page and do the following:

First click on the "watch tag" button that is circled.

[image]

Then you can find the tag in the "Watch tag"  in the side bar of the page.

Alternatively, you can click on the "edit" button and add a tag to the watched tags.

[image]